Confluent cli gives error when trying to start producer with value format set to avro
Currently trying to set up a local development environment with Confluent. I've installed the latest version of Confluent on my machine (Macbook Air M2) but when trying to attempt to start a producer, the following error occurs:
Error: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
Currently following the documentation that is provided here: https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/kafka-console-consumer-producer-avro/confluent.html
The command that I'm using to execute it is:
confluent kafka topic produce orders-avro --value-format avro --schema orders-avro-schema.json --bootstrap localhost:9092 --protocol PLAINTEXT

I've started up Confluent's services using
confluent local services start

Tried to create topics using the CLI. It does not throw this error when you're not providing "--value-format avro".

Please report the issue at https://github.com/confluentinc/cli/issues
